# Get "Internal System Error 1" after firebase test lab is done

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I run espresso testing on Firebase Test Lab. It looks like the test is passed but there is an internal system error at the end of the test.  Here is the detail:

```
C:\temp>gcloud firebase test android run --type instrumentation --app mytest.apk --test mytest-androidTest.apk --device model=Nexus10,version=22,locale=en,orientation=landscape --timeout 300s

Have questions, feedback, or issues? Get support by visiting:
  https://firebase.google.com/support/

Uploading [mytest.apk] to Firebase Test Lab...
Uploading [mytest-androidTest.apk] to Firebase Test Lab...
Raw results will be stored in your GCS bucket at [https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/test-lab-j9zwyqscmy0rw-k53tazzivjxvu/2017-10-06_10:05:06.963000_QXyn/]

Test [matrix-29xhyyz7dm2ko] has been created in the Google Cloud.
Firebase Test Lab will execute your instrumentation test on 1 device(s).
Creating individual test executions...done.

Test results will be streamed to [https://console.firebase.google.com/project/cova-int/testlab/histories/bh.9e7919885115a3e5/matrices/6160084542711433457].
10:06:09 Test is Pending
10:06:33 Starting attempt 1
10:06:33 Test is Running
10:07:47 Logging into the device
10:08:00 Installing APK: com.mytest
10:08:36 Installing APK: com.mytest.test
10:09:07 Running instrumentation test. Package: com.mytest.test testrunner: android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner useOrchestrator: false options: []
10:09:32 Instrumentation test has finished
10:09:38 Generating video
10:09:38 Retrieving performance samples
10:09:57 Retrieving test artifacts
10:10:03 Retrieving any crash results
10:10:52 Processing Logcat.
10:10:58 Done. Test time=26 (secs)
ERROR: (gcloud.firebase.test.android.run) Firebase Test Lab infrastructure failure: Internal System Error 1

C:\temp>
```

Does anyone have the same problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hello, Firebaser here.*  There was a problem with a recent code push in Test Lab, and the team is rolling it back to fix the problem you're seeing here.

Comment: I see. Thank you. :-)

Comment: hi Doug, could you please have a look at another Firebase Test Lab issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46778658/failed-to-start-an-instrument-test-from-firebase-gcloud-command-line ?
Any help is appreciated.