# How to execute a designated test suite class in Firebase Test Lab

Tags: android, firebase, gcloud, instrumentation, android-espresso

I have an espresso test suite class like this

```
package instrumentedtest;

import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.rules.ExternalResource;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        Test1.class,
        Test2.class,
        Test3.class
})

public class POSRuleSuite {
    @ClassRule
    public static ExternalResource testRule = new ExternalResource() {
        @Override
        protected void before() throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("Testing starts.........");
        }

        @Override
        protected void after() {
            System.out.println("Testing ends.........");
        }
    };
}
```

I set up a Firebase test with this suite class in Android Studio. I launch this firebase test from Android Studio and it does work.

[image]

But I failed to execute the test when I launch it from command line with Gcloud command.

```
gcloud firebase test android run ^
    --type instrumentation ^
    --app POS.apk ^
    --test POS-debug-androidTest.apk ^
    --test-runner-class=org.junit.runners.Suite ^
    --test-targets=instrumentedtest.POSRuleSuite ^
    --device model=Nexus10,version=22,locale=en,orientation=landscape ^
    --timeout 300s
```

Here is output

```
Uploading [POS.apk] to Firebase Test Lab...
Uploading [POS-debug-androidTest.apk] to Firebase Test Lab...
Raw results will be stored in your GCS bucket at [https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/test-lab-j9zwyqscmy0rw-k53tazzivjxvu/2017-10-19_14:25:20.055000_jPmA/]

ERROR: (gcloud.firebase.test.android.run) Http error while creating test matrix: ResponseError 400: Invalid test target for instrumentation test: instrumentedtest.POSRuleSuite

C:\git\POS>
```

Does anyone know how to get it work?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the reason, We have to inform the type of the **test-targets**. In this case the type is **class**. So that line should be in this way.

```
--test-targets="class instrumentedtest.POSRuleSuite"
```

You can also pass a string list with all yours targets, separated by comma, e.g.:

```
--test-targets="class instrumentedtest.POSRuleSuite,class instrumentedtest.AnotherRuleSuite"
```

[Firebase doc reference](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run)

Here the full request.

```
gcloud firebase test android run ^
    --type instrumentation ^
    --app POS.apk ^
    --test POS-debug-androidTest.apk ^
    --test-targets="class instrumentedtest.POSRuleSuite" ^
    --device model=Nexus10,version=22,locale=en,orientation=landscape ^
    --timeout 300s
```

Comment: Here's how to run a specific test within a designated test suite class: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55759800/2848676