# Firebase - How to run a specifc Android UI test class with command line that will run on firebase test labs?

Tags: android, firebase, android-espresso, firebase-test-lab

I am trying to run ONE specific espresso test class on firebase test labs through command line.  When I try to run the command below, all the test classes in the androidTest directory gets executed.

```html
gcloud firebase test android run \
  --type instrumentation \
  --app app-fred-stage-debug.apk \
  --test app-fred-stage-debug-androidTest.apk \
  --device model=Nexus6,version=21,locale=en,orientation=portrait
```

How do I specify the one test class I want to run on firebase test labs?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/command-line#running_your_instrumentation_tests) suggests that you can use the `--test-targets` flag to run a single test:

> For example, you can use the --test-targets flag to test just one
>   class used by your test APK, or to test just one method from a class
>   used by your test APK. To learn more, see `gcloud firebase test android run`.

That links you to the documentation for [gcloud firebase test](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run#--test-targets), which shows you the options for how to specify your specific tests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and link!  I managed to get my specific test class to work. 
 That documentation was super helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your command line:

```
--test-targets "class com.foo.ClassName" \
```

See more here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run#--test-targets

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple test classes which you want to run, you can pass them all at once separated by a comma.

```
--test-targets "class com.org.TestFoo,class com.org.TestBar" \
```

You can read the SO answer explaining this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46840030/7477675).