# How to execute a designated test in Firebase Test Lab

Tags: firebase, firebase-test-lab

I want to run one test from one test suite using `gcloud firebase test android run` but I can't figure out the syntax.

This command failed:

```
gcloud firebase test android run \
--type instrumentation \
--project locuslabs-android-sdk \
--app app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk \
--test app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk \
--device model=Pixel2,version=27,locale=en_US,orientation=portrait \
--verbosity debug \
--test-targets "class com.example.firebasetestlabplayground.ExampleInstrumentedTest.test002"
```

Error message:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.firebasetestlabplayground.ExampleInstrumentedTest.test002
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.doCreateRunner(TestLoader.java:72)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.getRunnersFor(TestLoader.java:104)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(TestRequestBuilder.java:789)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:539)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:382)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2075)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.firebasetestlabplayground.ExampleInstrumentedTest.test002" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasetestlabplayground.test-F71g9fZiJ95s1aLuzIJRsw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasetestlabplayground-EuQG5YDD3hrz6BPtBz2t6g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.firebasetestlabplayground.test-F71g9fZiJ95s1aLuzIJRsw==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.firebasetestlabplayground-EuQG5YDD3hrz6BPtBz2t6g==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
... 8 more
```

In my research, I came across [How to execute a designated test suite class in Firebase Test Lab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46838659/how-to-execute-a-designated-test-suite-class-in-firebase-test-lab) which was very helpful in getting me this far but it doesn't specify how to run a single test within the suite.

Also, according to https://github.com/piotrmadry/FirebaseTestLab-Android/issues/11, it should be possible to run a single test with the `--test-targets` parameter, but the documentation doesn't give an example at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run#--test-targets.

Answer (score 3):

After trial and error I discovered that I could specify a single test by using a `#` instead of a `.` between the test suite class name and the test name.

This command successfully ran a single test called `test002` in `com.example.firebasetestlabplayground.ExampleInstrumentedTest`:

```
gcloud firebase test android run \
--type instrumentation \
--project locuslabs-android-sdk \
--app app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk \
--test app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk \
--device model=Pixel2,version=27,locale=en_US,orientation=portrait \
--verbosity debug \
--test-targets "class com.example.firebasetestlabplayground.ExampleInstrumentedTest#test002"
```

Answer (score 0):

Michael, that syntax using # is documented in the [gcloud command reference](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run) (or add --help to your command above to get docs from the command line). That gcloud documentation in turn links to the full documentation for the [AndroidJUnitRunner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner) which also describes the full syntax.